# doxygen include call graph but exclude module files from documentation index

Tags: c, doxygen, call-graph

I'm trying to produce doxygen documentation with call+caller graphs included but excluding source modules from the output documentation. I don't want to have two files `doxytest.h` and `doxytest.c` duplicating some functions and exposing private functions to the documentation.

My understanding is that doxygen needs to process the source modules as input in order to generate the call+caller graphs. This is ok, but I have not found a way to include this functionality while excluding the source modules from the doc-build..

**problem**

> - generate call+callee graphs for functions in api ( `*.h` )
> - exclude source modules ( `*.c` ) from documentation

I've created the following doxytest project with three files which has this issue :

**project structure**

```
doxytest
    |-----doxygen.config
    |-----doxytest.h
    |-----doxytest.c
    |-----html
```

**doxygen.config**

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "doxytest"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.c

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = ./
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = *.h
PREDEFINED             =

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES

HAVE_DOT = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH = NO
CALL_GRAPH = YES
CALLER_GRAPH = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH = NO
COLLABORATION_GRAPH = NO

DISABLE_INDEX = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES
```

**doxytest.h**

```
#ifndef __doxytest__
#define __doxytest__

/*! @file
 */

void callee();
void middleman();
void caller();

#endif __doxytest__
```

**doxytest.c**

```
#include <doxytest.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void callee()
{
  ;
}

void middleman()
{
  callee();
}

void caller()
{
  middleman();
}
```

**current behaviour**

This configuration produces output with the call+callee graphs, but also includes `doxytest.c` documentation in the output [( screenshot1 )](http://snag.gy/8LIUd.jpg)

If I remove the `*.c` from FILE_PATTERNS, changing this line to :

```
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h
```

Then this removes the `*.c` documentation output but also the call+callee graphs.. [( screenshot2 )](http://snag.gy/V1lC3.jpg)

How can I fix ?

---

**hacks**

As a ( very dodgy ) workaround I'm currently doing two doxygen passes and merging the graph documentation into the api only index :

```
.PHONY:docs
docs:
  doxygen doxygen.pass1.cfg;
  mv html htmlpass1;
  doxygen doxygen.pass2.cfg;
  ls `cat doxygen.pass2.cfg | grep '^INPUT' | cut -d '=' -f2` | grep '\.h$$' | sed 's/\.h$$/_8h\*/g' | sed 's/^/rm -f .\/html\//g' 1>graph_api_docs;
  ls `cat doxygen.pass2.cfg | grep '^INPUT' | cut -d '=' -f2` | grep '\.h$$' | sed 's/\.h$$/_8h\*/g' | sed 's/^/cp .\/htmlpass1\//g' | sed 's/$$/ .\/html\//g' 1>>graph_api_docs;
  /bin/bash graph_api_docs;
  rm -rf htmlpass1 graph_api_docs;

.PHONY:clean
clean:
  rm -rf ./html;
```

Still looking for a proper solution to this problem..

Comment: Hoping I understood your problem right, did you change `FILE_PATTERNS = *.c`? This will consider only `.c` files and generate document once. Without `*.c` files, you won't get caller-callee graph.

Comment: i only want to document the public `*.h` api, but to include the accumulated callgraph info ( on the public functions ) from the private `*.c`. so the private `*.c` must be read to produce the graphs, but i then want to exclude the private `*.c` from the doxygen index..